# How to detect number dialing events in broadcastreceiver in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

How to detect number dialing events in Broad Cast Receiver in android?

Answer (score 0):

Create below step in code.

Create service.
Implement View.OnKeyListener interface in service

```
@Override 
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
 { 
     // Do Code here 
 } 
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0) 
{} 
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1) 
{} 
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```

This is possible way to do what you want. I am not sure whether this will help you. But give a try.

Comment: I have use already used this technique but key listener doesn't work on backgound serivce , it is only used in View like in applications i think ?